# blackberry sqlite error

Tags: sqlite, blackberry, io, disk

What triggers a disk I/O error? I know if the disk runs out of space, attempt to write there would cause this error. Is there any other scenerio where this error is thrown?

Answer (score 0):

I would say there several possible reasons:

1) SQLite file can be created on SD card only for many devices. So if you try to use internal memory check that your target device supports it. There is no resource that clearly says - yes/no. Torch and all new 7 OS devices support it.

2) SD card filesystem is not available from device start immediately. So you have autostart app you have to wait until system notify that it's ready for using. Take look on `FileSystemListener` class.

3) During debug/charge SD card is mounted (depends on device settings). So SD card is also not available during this time.

4) File system is full.

5) DB isn't closed properly during last application run or other app is using it now.